# Grails data binding

Tags: data-binding, grails, groovy

A Grails controller received is called with the following request parameters:

```
defaultPrice[0].amount  22
defaultPrice[0].currency 1
defaultPrice[0].id  
defaultPrice[1].amount  33
defaultPrice[1].currency 3
defaultPrice[1].id
```

I've defined the following command class:

```
class PriceCommand {
    BigDecimal amount
    Integer currency
    Integer id
}
```

I attempt to bind the request parameters to a `List' in the action

```
def save = {List<PriceCommand> defaultPrice ->

}
```

But within the action, `defaultPrice` is null.

Answer (score 3):

It requires an command with **existing list** of data, with specified name, that will be filled with data from request.

Try

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils
import org.apache.commons.collections.Factory

class PriceListCommand {
   List<PriceCommand> defaultPrice = ListUtils.lazyList([], {new PriceCommand()} as Factory)
}
```

and use this command inside controller. It should works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking but it may help...

1.) I think indexed params only work if you have a parent-child or one-to-many relationship.  For example you might need to introduce a `PriceCommandParent` which contains a list of `PriceCommand`.  **I may be wrong on this** and I welcome any corrections.

2.) I've found that indexed params aren't as magically as some of the other areas of Grails/Groovy so sometimes i'd rather deal with the mapping myself.  Below is how i've handled it in the past....

```
def things = []

params.each{name, value->
    if (name.matches('^(thing\\[\\d+\\])$')){ //<-- look for 'thing[x]'
        things.add(new Thing(params[name]);
    }   
}
```

Let me know if any of this is of help